# Use Core Data for application similar to Dropbox

Tags: ios, core-data, dropbox

I am writing an iOS application similar to Dropbox. My main question right now is how to organise storage for files.

I want to use Core Data to store files or folders. The file entity will have these attributes:

- file path
- file name
- views count
- etc

Is this a good solution to select Core Data for this task? Also I will need to search through the files. But here's one issue. At start time, I just load files and folders for the root directory and don't know what each folder contains. So to retrieve the files for the appropriate folder, I need to open it. But to search I suppose I need to know about all files on the server.

Do I need to retrieve the whole file tree from the server with minimal data? Or maybe I should create a search request that returns me JSON with all searched files. Thank you for your advice.

If you can maybe drop a link to some example explaining how to organise a mirror of the files that are on the server.